# AS3 + XML + MouseEvent

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5

I want to create a flash movie that uses XML to load some data. I want each line of data to appear one by one when a user clicks on the screen. So far I have all my data added to the screen but I'm not sure how to write the clicking mechanism for this.

I have tried adding a function that allows me to click to remove and object as seen here:

```
muppet_name0.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToKermit);

function fl_ClickToKermit(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   muppet_name0.visible = false;
}
```

But I'm not sure how to make it reappear. How can I add a MouseClick event that will remove an object while simultaneously adding a new object?

My Document Class Follows

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent; 

public class MuppetsDoc extends MovieClip {

    public var myData:XML = <data>
        <item>
            <a>Kermit the Frog</a>
            <b>Jim Henson</b>
            <c>1955</c>
        </item>
        <item>
            <a>Miss Piggy</a>
            <b>Frank Oz</b>
            <c>1974</c>
        </item>
        <item>
            <a>Animal</a>
            <b>Frank Oz</b>
            <c>1975</c>
        </item>

        <item>
            <a>The Swedish Chef</a>
            <b>Jim Henson/Frank Oz</b>
            <c>1975</c>
        </item>


    </data>;




    public function MuppetsDoc() {


        // constructor code
        //trace(myData);
        //muppets_txt.text = myData.item[2].a.length();
        var aTxt:String = myData.item[2].a.text();
        muppet_name0.appendText(myData.item[0].a.text());

        muppet_puppet0.appendText(myData.item[0].b.text());


        muppet_year0.appendText(myData.item[0].c.text());

        muppet_name1.appendText(myData.item[1].a.text());

        muppet_puppet1.appendText(myData.item[1].b.text());


        muppet_year1.appendText(myData.item[1].c.text());

        muppet_name2.appendText(myData.item[2].a.text());

        muppet_puppet2.appendText(myData.item[2].b.text());


        muppet_year2.appendText(myData.item[2].c.text());

        muppet_name3.appendText(myData.item[3].a.text());

        muppet_puppet3.appendText(myData.item[3].b.text());


        muppet_year3.appendText(myData.item[3].c.text());





    }
}

}
```

Comment: Somehow I fail to see a question there... Please read the FAQ.

Comment: Also voted to close unless you refine your question, what are you attempting to add an event listener to, what have you tried, what is failing?  That type of info will be necessary in order to provide any good feedback.

Comment: Added what I've tried and a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do but I think you what you're looking for is something like this:

```
function fl_ClickToKermit(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   muppet_name0.alpha = (muppet_name0.alpha == 0) : 1 ? 0;
}
```

Everytime on click you invert its `alpha` value. When you're using `visible` the `DisplayObject` becomes disabled so it can't be clicked. By using `alpha` instead your `DisplayObject` stays enabled but is not visible anymore.

Check the docs for more info:

[`DisplayObject.visible`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#visible)
[`DisplayObject.alpha`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#alpha)

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, but when I added your code nothing changed. I'm still able to make the text invisible but I'm not able to make it reappear.

Comment: Awesome thank you. I am now generating some errors though - 
Line 74 1078: Label must be a simple identifier.
Line 74 1084: Syntax error: expecting colon before semicolon.
Line 75 1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before rightbrace.              -                                                                             the lines it's referring to are:                          muppet_name0.alpha = (muppet_name0.alpha == 0) : 1 ? 0;
}

Comment: There is NOTHING wrong with the code rvmook has posted. Check your other code for errors.